# prove $\deg_{\alpha,L}\mid\deg_{\alpha,K}$ if $\alpha$ is separable and $K(\alpha)/K$ is normal

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials, separable-extension

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $K$ be a field, $\alpha \in \overline{K}$ a separable element s.t. $K(\alpha)/K$ is normal, and let $L/K$ be some finite subextension of $\overline{K}$.
> Prove that  $\deg_{\alpha,L}\mid\deg_{\alpha,K}$

---

**My attempt:**

We know that $\begin{array}{c}
\left[L\left(\alpha\right):L\right]=\deg_{\alpha,L}\\
\left[K\left(\alpha\right):K\right]=\deg_{\alpha,K}
\end{array}$ and therefore $\deg_{\alpha,L}\mid\deg_{\alpha,K}$ iff $\left[L\left(\alpha\right):L\right]\mid\left[K\left(\alpha\right):K\right]$ but since $$\begin{array}{c}
\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\right]=\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\left(\alpha\right)\right]\left[K\left(\alpha\right):K\right]\\
\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\right]=\left[L\left(\alpha\right):L\right]\left[L:K\right]
\end{array}$$ we get that $$\left[L\left(\alpha\right):L\right]=\frac{\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\right]}{\left[L:K\right]}\qquad\frac{\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\right]}{\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\left(\alpha\right)\right]}=\left[K\left(\alpha\right):K\right]$$ meaning in order to prove $\deg_{\alpha,L}\mid\deg_{\alpha,K}$ I need to just show (at least) one of the following holds:

1. $\left[L\left(\alpha\right):L\right]\mid\left[K\left(\alpha\right):K\right]$
2. $\left[L\left(\alpha\right):K\left(\alpha\right)\right]\mid\left[L:K\right]$

Now since $L/K$ is finite we can write $L=K\left(a_{1},\ldots,a_{k}\right)$ and since $\alpha$ is separable and $K(\alpha)/K$ is normal, it is also Galois.

From this point on I am stuck. I can't find a way to connect $K$ and $L$ in any way. I thought about looking at the normal closure of $L$ but didn't find this useful.

I also noticed that we can embbed $\mathrm{Aut}_L (L(\alpha))\hookrightarrow Gal(K(\alpha ))$ and get that $\left|\mathrm{Aut}_{L}\left(L\left(\alpha\right)\right)\right|\mid\left[K\left(\alpha\right):K\right]$ but again I can't do anything from here because I don't know that  $L(\alpha)/L$ is Galois.

Comment: Continuing your argument, could you not just take the normal closure of $L(\alpha)/L$, say adding $S=\lbrace\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_n\rbrace$ such that $L(\alpha,S)/L$ is normal, then use that $K(\alpha,S)=K(\alpha)$ and use the usual Galois argument, and finally applying $[L(\alpha)/L]\mid [L(\alpha,S)/L]$?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Is $S$ the set of \alpha 's conjugates? On second thought, Isn't it right that since $K(\alpha)/K$ is normal it contains all roots of $f_{\alpha,K}$ and therefore $L(\alpha)/K$ also already contains all those roots?

Comment: You are completely right, I missed that as well. $K(\alpha)/K$ being normal means that $K(\alpha)$ contains all the conjugates of $\alpha$, and as $K(\alpha)\subset L(\alpha)$, the latter does as well, so $L(\alpha)$ must be the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $L$, thus it is normal. With this lemma, the Galois argument is directly applicable.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Thanks for the help! wouldn't have found this without your guidance